# Which items are Charms?

Tags: knights-of-pen-paper-2

In Knights of Pen and Paper 2, you can enchant weapons in crafting with scrolls and with charms. I've found the scrolls in consumables, and the weapons are easy enough to come by. What items count as Charms?

I've tried:

- Crafting Materials (Pound of Rock)
- Gems (Mana and Health)
- Special items (Enchanted Cushion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will be able to know if an item is a charm because it will have *Charm* in it's name.

Some examples are:

- Burn Charm
- Confusion Charm
- Poison Charm
- Rage Charm
- Stun Charm
- Weakness Charm
- Wound Charm

Charms can be found rarely in the dungeons and only once per dungeon so once you obtain one, there is no chance of obtaining another from clearing the other rooms.

Answer (score 4):

With the latest update, crafting 3 pounds of rocks produces a random Charm.

Answer (score -1):

Charms can be found uncommonly in dungeons, also if you finish all the dungeon rooms, you have a chance of obtaining one.